# Смена картинок циклом в UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

Мне надо менять картинки циклом в `UIImageView`. Если что про стандартные методы анимации, которыми владеет `UIImageView` я вкурсе, но надо сделать именно циклом. Вот мой код:

```
- (void)startAnimating {

    for (int i = 0; i < allImages.count; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        [self changeImageByIndex:i];
    }  
}


- (void)changeImageByIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    [imageView setImage:[allImages objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

в массиве `allImages` лежат все картинки. на `sleep(1)` тоже не обращайте внимание - это временный костыль, который уберется) сам факт в том, что тело цикла действительно выполняется раз в 1 секунду, НО! Картинка показыается только самая последняя. Т.е. во время работы цикла ничего не заметно, а по окончанию ХОП! и мы видим последнюю картинку. Почему они не обновляются?

Comment: Прикольно. судя по всему, обновления UI не происходят во время выполнения for, а когда все итерации прошли и программа вышла из for, сразу обрабатывается вся 'очередь'.

Comment: Ты sleep-ом лочишь runloop, вот ничего и не обновляется

Comment: Вот конкретно `for`, Max все правильно написал. В реальных проектах не стоит так делать. Для такой задачи либо запустить анимацию у `UIImageView`, либо таймерами и, если хочется совсем правильно, то `CADisplayLink` (что-то типа таймеров на update на экране)

Comment: @Cy-4AH проблема не в этом. сделайте for на 10к повторений  без sleep и в нем меняйте картинку - будет тот же результат, она поменяется после того, как приложение выйдет из цикла (10к повторений чтоб было достаточно долго, чтобы увидеть)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, ну здасьте. Сам же в своём ответе написал: цикл for работает на основном потоке, фактически блокируя его. А теперь говоришь проблема не в этом. Да без слипа она не поменяется 10к раз а один, последний, когда цикл в runloop отработает.

Comment: @Cy-4AH я о том говорю, что не sleep лочит, а весь for

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, цикл for работает на основном потоке, фактически блокируя его, таким образом обновления UI не могут выполниться, пока цикл не закончится. Чтобы это побороть, предлагаю, цикл запускать на не основном потоке, а обновления UI отправлять на основной.

```
- (void)startAnimating {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        for (int i = 0; i < allImages.count; i++) {
            sleep(1);
            [self changeImageByIndex:i];
        }  
    });
}


- (void)changeImageByIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [imageView setImage:[allImages objectAtIndex:index]];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994402/function-after-animation-image-sequence Вот наиболее правильное решение, `CADisplayLink`, суммируется время с последней смены картинки, как только оно вревышает длину одного кадра - выставляется следующая картинка. По выставлению последнего кадра display link убивается. В твоём случае ты полностью занимаешь главный поток, ведь sleep не отдаёт управление UI-подсистеме, поэтому перерисовка imageView не вызывается до тех пор пока система UI-подсистема не получит контроль над главный тредом. Таймеры и диспатчи - это полумеры, а для применения онлайн изменений к UI правильнее использовать `CADisplayLink`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)startAnimatingWhithDuration:(NSInteger)duration {

[self.allImages enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView duration:duration options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [self.imageView setImage:obj];
    }];

}];
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score -2):

Привет

```
func startAnimation() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
        1,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(nextImage),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)
}

func nextImage() {
    imageIndex += 1
    print("TICK = \(imageIndex)")
    if imageIndex == 5 { timer?.invalidate() }
}
```

Это всё что тебе нужно знать. Можешь что угодно делать по этому таймеру.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что автор пишет, что он в курсе, как работают анимации, но для своей задачи, просит подсказать, как это сделать используя цикл. Опять же в вопросе стоит тэг objective-c

Comment: Я прекрасно обратил внимание, в данном контексте всё что нужно от цикла это индекс. А код здесь не такой уж сложный чтоб на objective переписывать, я бы словами написал, просто так нагляднее

Comment: так чего сразу не на php код? тоже было бы не сложно

Comment: Благодарю всех за ответ. Доберусь до кода в течении часа и попробую. А то, что на SWIFT написано - ничего страшного, я пойму)